# virtualbox on WIN machine

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I read about the virtual box , and I have some questions

Before my question short snapshot about the virtual box

1. Virtual box give the ability to work on Linux environment from the Win machine
2. Virtual box is flexibility to start any linux from .iso file as red-hat fedora , ubuntu etc

So what isn’t clearly is that:

Is it possible to see the file system and files of the WIN  ( C:\ and D:\ ) from the linux machine?

Is it possible to run WIN CLI command from the Linux machine?

what about the LAN interface of the WIN machine , is this LAN shared also to the linux machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do my best to provide some answers.

*Is it possible to see the file system and files of the WIN ( C:\ and D:\ ) from the linux machine?*
Not as far as i know. By default the only files you'll see are the .vdi (Virtual Disk Image) and the .vbox (VirtualBox Machine Definition).
If memory serves me right the .vdi is the hdd itself of the virtual machine and the .vbox is a file that contains the specifications of the virtual machine.
There might be some sort of out-of-the-box solution that i don't know off tough.

*Is it possible to run WIN CLI command from the Linux machine?*
This is something you can achieve from within Linux itself. There's a tool called [winexe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinExe) that allows you to run windows cmd/powershell commands from linux.

*what about the LAN interface of the WIN machine , is this LAN shared also to the linux machine ?*
Yes but this is configured by settings. Most of the times you give the VM a NIC and it'll obtain an ip adress from your network.

however i'm not an authority when it comes down to virtualbox. I do happily use it to store some test machines.
Hope that helped. Cheers.

Comment: about the LAN eth is it possible to set the IP LAN of the linux virtual box as for example 192.9.200.1 and the WIN as 192.9.200.2 so LINUX can talk with the IP of the WIN?